# GUIDEWIRE : How to display the the query builder result in UI?

Tags: guidewire

I am using query builder to return number of search result from the database table. Now I would like to display the result in the UI by only first three rows. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryAPI is **lazy**, when .toList(), .toTypedArray(), .toCollection(), .where(), etc occurs all resultset is retrieved (**eager**).

I recommend you to use this:

```
var limit = 3
var rs = Query.make(entity.XXX)...select()
rs.setPageSize(limit)
var paginatedRS = com.google.common.collect.Iterables.limit(rs,limit)
```

**setPageSize** method specifies how many rows will be fetch "by page"

**limit** method make a new iterator that have only the first (limit) rows